# Extend ViewModel onto a dynamically loaded piece of markup in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

On my page I have a several nested KnockoutJS view models applied to several logic-rich markup regions.

From within my `FactViewModel` I am loading a div with a list of comments to that "Fact". This is taking place via a click handler in `FactViewModel`. The ajax-loaded markup contains `data-bind` attributes but as expected there are not bound to the viewmodel elemets. How do I extend the view model to a dynamically loaded markup to process, for example, a click handlers, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at Knockout's templating.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

You want to define a client side template, either included as a fixed part of your initial HTML, or load and attach it to the document dynamically. You don't really post any code, so it's hard to post any specifics, but I make use of KOs templates, and I feel they work quite well (and yes, I also apply them to dynamically loaded data).

Comment: Thats the way. Thank you. I didn't post code since I needed a purely theoretical guidance on the matter.